# How to handle interruptions (0 values) over a certain period in time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, arima, missing-data, garch, tobit-regression

Is there a way that I can combine two models for time series?

I am trying to predict the production of tomatoes per week per $m^2$ (black line), based on light (orange) and temperature (magenta).[image]

At the beginning of each year, the production is 0 roughly until week 13.

I am using a categorical predictor to specify whether the production is 0 or not (the predictor has value 1 in weeks 1-13 and 0 elsewhere). I am modeling the series using ARIMA, but I would want the prediction to be 0 over weeks 1-13.

Is there a way that I could specify that in a certain period $y_t = 0$ and in other periods $y_t = \beta X_t + \eta_t $ where $\eta_t$ follows an ARIMA model?

I also see a problem with the variability in the black time series: since there's no variability in the beginning of the year, do I have to account for that by GARCH modeling or some other method?

Just in case, I have put the data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10aSusTJdEAnEZwlzJSrg8QyfkR_E_tbQLEhUjCZv--0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Good implemetations of ARIMA (like that in R) make it possible to estimate and predict even if part of the series are unobserved.

Knowing that some part of the series (week 1--13) is always zero, I would make a dataset replacing those parts by NA's (NA=Not Available), estimate and predict, and finally replace what the model outputs for week 1--13 by zero's.

Maybe there is a more principled approach, but I would start with that.